Firebase storage security rule: cannot nest firestore queries
I found this weird behavior where using a document field to query another document is not working as expected when setting Firebase storage security rules:
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    function getUser(uid) {
        let path = /databases/(default)/documents/users/$(uid);
        return firestore.get(path);
    }
    match /users/{uid}/{filename=**} {
        allow read, write: 
          // if getUser(uid) == "123"; // Runs
          // if getUser(uid).data.uid == "123"; // Runs
          if getUser(getUser(uid).data.id).data.id == "123"; // Exception
    }
  }
}


My actual use case trying to use doc1.doc2_id to look up doc2. I have very similar code working with Firestore security rule. But it doesn't for Firebase Storage security rule. I am not sure how to get around this limitation.

The examples in the documentation don't assign a path variable with let. Have you tried it exactly as they show it?

Let is not the issue. I can reproduce the exact error without using functions. I also see that the outer firestore.get is not evaluated when the exception occurs.
          if firestore.get(
            /databases/(default)/documents/users/$(
              firestore.get(
               /databases/(default)/documents/users/$(uid)).data.id
            )
           ) == "123"; // Exception


If you're unable to get anything to work, as close to the documented examples as possible, then you should file an issue with Firebase support.  We'll be unlikely to help if you can't get the most basic example to work as documented.

Filed. Thank you Doug. Will report back with updates.
